# How to remove the ".svc" extension in RESTful WCF service?

Tags: wcf, rest

In my knowledge, the RESTful WCF still has ".svc" in its URL.

For example, if the service interface is like

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Value/{value}")]
string GetDataStr(string value);
```

The access URI is like "http://machinename/Service.svc/Value/2". In my understanding, part of REST advantage is that it can hide the implementation details. A RESTful URI like "http://machinename/Service/value/2" can be implemented by any RESTful framework, but a "http://machinename/Service.svc/value/2" exposes its implementation is WCF.

How can I remove this ".svc" host in the access URI?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662555/how-can-i-override-a-svc-file-in-my-routing-table

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In IIS 7 you can use the [Url Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) as explained in this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/endpoint/archive/2008/08/22/rest-in-wcf-part-ix-controlling-the-uri.aspx).

In IIS 6 you could write an [http module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) that will rewrite the url:

```
public class RestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += delegate
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            string path = ctx.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;

            int i = path.IndexOf('/', 2);
            if (i > 0)
            {
                string svc = path.Substring(0, i) + ".svc";
                string rest = path.Substring(i, path.Length - i);
                ctx.RewritePath(svc, rest, ctx.Request.QueryString.ToString(), false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And there's a nice [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/extensionless.aspx?display=Print) how to achieve extensionless urls in IIS 6 without using third party ISAPI modules or wildcard mapping.

Comment: int i = path.IndexOf('/', 2); must be int i = path.LastIndexOf('/', 2);

Answer (score 47):

I know this post is a bit old now, but if you happen to be using .NET 4, you should look at using URL Routing (introduced in MVC, but brought into core ASP.NET).

In your app start (global.asax), just have the following route configuration line to setup the default route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("mysvc", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyServiceClass)));
```

then your URLs would look like this:

```
http://servername/mysvc/value/2
```

HTH

Comment: The best solution (if using 4.0)

Comment: This fails in asp.net mvc 4, since all the other links generated by mvc will now point to the service.

Comment: you have to configure your route table accordingly so that your routes don't collide.  You can use a route debugging tool like Route Debugger (codeplex), or Glimpse.

Comment: So when you use this you can remove the SVC (markup) file, correct?

Comment: i believe so, but do the due dilligence, test and report your findings here for good measure.

Comment: Don't forget to add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.Activation` to your project if it doesn't exist. (Default WCF project in VS2012 doesn't seem to include this)

Comment: and don't forget to add this to the Global.asax.cs:

`using System.Web.Routing;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;`

Comment: Also, I've just found that if you specify your service name as an empty string, the request can be made without any service name - e.g. https://localhost:1234/MyMethodName?param=value

Answer (score 4):

Here's more detailed info using the IIS 7 Rewrite Module, or using a custom module:
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/570695.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is also a way to eliminate the physical .svc files altogether. This can be done with a `VirtualPathProvider`.

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/350f2cb6-febd-4978-ae65-f79735d412db

Answer (score 2):

Its easy on IIS 7 - use a [URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)

On IIS 6 I found its easiest to use the [ISAPI Rewrite module](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) which lets you define a set of regular expressions that map the request Urls to the .svc file...

Answer (score 2):

In IIS6 or 7, you can use [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com), a free rewriting filter.  Here's the rule I used:

```
# Iirf.ini
#

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteLog  c:\inetpub\iirfLogs\iirf-v2.0.services
RewriteLogLevel 3
StatusInquiry  ON  RemoteOk
CondSubstringBackrefFlag *
MaxMatchCount 10

# remove the .svc tag from external URLs
RewriteRule  ^/services/([^/]+)(?<!\.svc)/(.*)$    /services/$1.svc/$2  [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your global.asax

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.RewritePath(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
               Request.Path, "/rest/(.*)/", "/$1.svc/"));
}
```

This will replace /rest/Service1/arg1/arg2 by /Service1.svc/arg1/arg2