# WCF 3.5 - Remove SVC Extension - Special Case

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have several RESTful endpoints like such:

```
System.Security.Role.svc
System.Security.User.svc
etc.
```

This is meant to be a namespace so our RESTful URL's would look like:

```
/rest/{class namespace}/{actions}
```

I have tried a few examples to get the SVC extension removed when my endpoint has multiple periods in it, however, nothing seems to work.

I have tested with the WCF REST Contrib package (http://wcfrestcontrib.codeplex.com/), this example (http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/570695.aspx), and another StackOverflow post ([How to remove the ".svc" extension in RESTful WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355165/how-to-remove-thie-svc-extension-in-restful-wcf-service)).

This works great when my endpoint is something like this:

```
Echo.svc
```

It will properly remove the SVC extension.

Any ideas on how to handle endpoints with multiple periods in the endpoint name?

EDIT:
After some further testing, I found out that it is failing because whenever you do:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
```

If the endpoint contains multiple periods, it strips off everything after the endpoint causing all of the standard IHttpModule's to fail.

Example:

If I call http://localhost/services/Echo/test, my relative app file path has a returned value of:

```
~/echo/test
```

However, if I make a call as http://localhost/services/System.Security.User/test, then my relative app file path has a returned value of:

```
~/system.security.user
```

I am missing the '/test' on the end in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution - [How to remove the ".svc" extension in RESTful WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355165/how-to-remove-thie-svc-extension-in-restful-wcf-service/355471#355471)