# ASP.NET: What does this HttpModule do? System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me the purpose of this HttpModule?  It's showing up on my HttpModuleCollection list, but I don't know what's it's for.

```
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule
```

I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule` come from because you installed "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" / "Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation" feature. If you don't need the feature you can uninstall it of remove the module from your web.config. The less unused modules you load the more quickly run your web application.

If you install this feature **after**  the installation of .NET 4 framework on your server you can receive problems described in http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/04/28/system-typeloadexception-for-system-servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-in-asp-net-4.aspx.

In general an HTTP module is called on every request in response to the BeginRequest() and EndRequest() events. As a result, the module runs before and after a request is processed. In the section "How HTTP Modules Work" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=VS.100).aspx you can read more about HTTP modules.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx describes how to create a Custom HTTP Module. Some small custom modules can be really helpful. For example, you can read in [How to remove the ".svc" extension in RESTful WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355165/how-to-remove-thie-svc-extension-in-restful-wcf-service) a code example (which originate from the book "RESTful .NET", Chapter 5, page 96) "Removing the .SVC Extension from WCF REST URLs". In http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/570695.aspx you can read how to do the same with respect of "IIS 7 Rewrite Module".

The general information about HTTP module is not a part of your question, but I inserted it to better understanding what `Activation.HttpModule` do, and what other more useful modules  you can use or write yourself.

Answer (score 4):

This module is what allows [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) (Windows Communication Foundation) services to work (starting in .net Framework 3.0).

You can safely ignore it and it shouldn't cause trouble.  If you really want to get rid of it, you can remove it from your root web.config file (e.g. in 
 \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config).  But I suggest leaving it there just in case you need WCF at some point.

Answer (score -3):

A http module is a .net assembly that is called every time your web  application gets a request. This is the standard one that asp.net provides that connects your .net web application code to the IIS web infrastructure.

See [here for an explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

> HTTP Modules
>
> An HTTP module is an assembly that is
> called on every request that is made
> to your application. HTTP modules are
> called as part of the request pipeline
> and have access to life-cycle events
> throughout the request. HTTP modules
> therefore let you examine incoming
> requests and take action based on the
> request. They also let you examine the
> outgoing response and modify it.
>
> In IIS 6.0, the ASP.NET request
> pipeline is separate from the Web
> server request pipeline. In IIS 7.0,
> the ASP.NET request pipeline and the
> Web server request pipeline can be
> integrated into a common request
> pipeline. In IIS 7.0, this is referred
> to as Integrated mode. The unified
> pipeline has several benefits for
> ASP.NET developers. For example, it
> lets managed-code modules receive
> pipeline notifications for all
> requests, even if the requests are not
> for ASP.NET resources. However, if you
> want, you can run IIS 7.0 in Classic
> mode, which emulates ASP.NET running
> in IIS 6.0. For more information, see
> ASP.NET Application Life Cycle
> Overview for IIS 7.0.
>
> ASP.NET HTTP modules are like ISAPI
> filters because they are invoked for
> all requests. However, they are
> written in managed code and are fully
> integrated with the life cycle of an
> ASP.NET application. You can put
> custom module source code in the
> App_Code folder of your application,
> or you can put compiled custom modules
> as assemblies in the Bin folder of an
> application.
>
> ASP.NET uses modules to implement
> various application features, which
> includes forms authentication,
> caching, session state, and client
> script services. In each case, when
> those services are enabled, the module
> is called as part of a request and
> performs tasks that are outside the
> scope of any single page request.
> Modules can consume application events
> and can raise events that can be
> handled in the Global.asax file. For
> more information about application
> events, see ASP.NET Application Life
> Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0 and
> ASP.NET Application Life Cycle
> Overview for IIS 7.0.

Comment: I know what an Http module is, just not this one. Can you explain in further detail what you mean my "onnects your .net web application code to the IIS web infrastructure." it seems strange to me that this would be implemented as an http module - if this is what it does it's hardly optional.

Comment: The text you quoted is about httpmodules in general - my question is about a specific module.