# ASP.Net MVC 404 errors when route contains an .svc extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an ASP.Net MVC 2 site set up under IIS7 using the integrated pipeline with the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "mycontroller/{name}/{*path}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", path = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

There are no other routes above this route, but whenever I try and access the above route with a path value that has an `.svc` extension, for example:

> http://localhost/MyVirtualDirectory/mycontroller/test/somepath.svc

ASP.Net returns a 404 error without executing my controller (I have a log message call at the start of the action method).  If I change the extension to something benign (like .txt) it works perfectly, so seems that somewhere along the line **ASP.Net** is interpreting the request as a standard ASP.Net call to a web service that doesn't exist - this is definitely an ASP.Net 404 response (not an IIS response).

What could be causing this, and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I override a .svc file in my routing table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662555/how-can-i-override-a-svc-file-in-my-routing-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is IIS configured to server .svc files?  You may need to [add the .svc MIME type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx) to IIS

In IIS

1. Select your website
2. Click on MIME Types
3. Click on 'Add' to add the .svc MIME type

**Update**

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662555/how-can-i-override-a-svc-file-in-my-routing-table/3664291#3664291)

> The problem you're running into is due to a build provider that is registered for .svc files. This build provider is registered by the default machine level web.config file.

Update your web.config

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".svc"/>            
    </buildProviders>
```

[Phil Haack's full post on the issue](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/09/07/routing-and-build-providers.aspx)

Comment: Tried that - it doesn't have any effect - Also if I use an  unknown extension (like .bob) it works fine.

Comment: Ok, this can be replicated in a the default new application template, so I had a quick look around and found some more information. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The build provider thing did it.