# Unable to call WCF method with browser

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I developed a WCF service application and deployed it to IIS 8.

With a browser, when I go to http://localhost:6000/CustomService.svc, it shows
"You have created a service" and other information. This means the service is successfully deployed.

But when I go to http://localhost:6000/testservice/date/2016/12/1, it showed HTTP 404 Not Found.

Here is service contract:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;

    namespace WCF
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface ICustomService
        {
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "date/{year}/{month}/{day}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
            [OperationContract]
            string GetDate(string day, string month, string year); 
        }
    }
```

Here is implemented class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCF
{
    public class CustomService : ICustomService
    {
        public string GetDate(string day, string month, string year)
        {
            return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month), Convert.ToInt32(day)).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CustomServiceBehavior" name="WCF.CustomService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF.ICustomService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6000/testservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Where could the problem be? I basically copied most of the stuff from https://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with no problem for me.

[image]

using this URL:

http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc/date/2017/1/31

and this config file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <security>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Go to `IIS Manager` right-click your .SVC file, select browse and make sure you have the correct base address in your config file. Your base address looks more like an `IIS Express` address.

Comment: What would be my URL in my case? You are using "WcfService1" which is what? Can your example uses the same namespace and class names as mine?

Comment: Pls see my last comment.

Comment: When I browse the the .SVC file, it opens up as http://localhost:6000/CustomService.svc on the browser. It is always "localhost", even when I run "Start Debugging" on Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, note that this base address does not match the one you posted in your question.

Comment: Is it `/testservice` or `/CustomerService.svc` ?

Comment: Did you try in your dev machine or in the server you deployed?

Comment: What should be the correct url to call my service method?

Comment: Should be whatever you see when you go to IIS Manager and browse your SVC file.

Comment: When I browse svc file in browser, it doesn't say how to call my method. Why don't you take my codes and try it? Don't change anything at all and tell me if it works.

Comment: The url to call your method can only be one of two things: 1)  http://localhost:6000/testservice/date/2017/1/31 or 2)  http://localhost:6000/CustomService.svc/date/2017/1/31.

Comment: I did use your code, just the project name is not the same.

Comment: Note that my config file does not explicitly set the base address and sets the contract. Yours does exactly the opposite.

Comment: I'm merely following the example from https://weblogs.asp.net/kiyoshi/wcf-using-webhttpbinding-for-rest-services . Anyway, I removed the <host>...</host> part from Web.config, and then run it again from Visual Studio. Again, it is returning 404 when I tried to access http://localhost:57371/testservice/date/12/1/1.

Comment: Hi jstreet, I just tried with http://localhost:6000/CustomService.svc/date/2017/1/31 and it works. Not sure why it didn't work earlier. I must have entered something wrongly earlier.

Comment: But it doesn't work with http://localhost:6000/testservice/date/2017/1/31. Does it mean that I can't change the "CustomService.svc" part of the URL to something else?

Comment: You can sure change it to something else if you change it in your project, re-compile and re-deploy it, so everything is consistent.

Comment: But it seems that we can't really get rid of the ".svc" in the URL even if I change the service file to some other name.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355165/how-to-remove-the-svc-extension-in-restful-wcf-service).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WCF test client that comes baked into Visual Studio. It's located here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe. Open the test client, add the service and make your call.

You can use fiddler or some other network request capturing tool to see what URL is being requested by your service. Hopefully that should allow you to troubleshoot further.

Here is the MSDN for the WCF test client.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't have IIS on my development laptop. I deployed it to a server with IIS, and on that server, there is no Visual Studio.

Comment: You can use IIS express. That comes with visual studio. There isn't a start or run option when your project is "Set as startup project"?

Comment: I can run "Start Debugging" from my development laptop. A browser will open with http://localhost:57371/, which shows the directory of my development files. Then what next? When I go to http://localhost:57371/testservice/date/12/1/1, it is also showing me HTTP 404.

Comment: Take localhost:57371/whateverthepathistoyourservice.svc and put it into the wcf client

Comment: I ran WCFTestClient, then in File -> Add Service, I entered my service http://localhost:57371/CustomService.svc. Then what next? In the program left pane, it is just showing "My Service Projects", and on the right pane it is the "Start Page".

Comment: WCFTestClient can't be used to test REST, only SOAP.  It looks like OP is trying to do RESTful WCF.

Comment: Where does it say that? I'm pretty sure it's just a missing config option, but I don't know what config he is missing.

Comment: Where in my codes does it indicates RESTful? Does it mean I can't call my service from a browser if it is RESTful?

Comment: He is probably referring to the WebGet attribute you have on your GetDate method on the interface.

Comment: <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF.ICustomService"/> Try adding this line below your other endpoint entry (right above host)

Comment: Hi Brendan, I added the line as you suggested, so now I have two <endpoint> lines: my original one with binding="webHttpBinding", and yours with binding="basicHttpBinding". I then started debugging from Visual Browser, and in the launched browser, I entered http://localhost:57371/testservice/date/2016/12/1 and again I got HTTP 404 Not Found.

Comment: The config setting I mentioned was just to help debug from the WCF test client. (I'm not 100% sure it will work).